# Updating Apache from 3.1 to 4.5.1

Tags: apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to drag my libraries up to current, but I'm having trouble finding a few things in the API's.  I've looked in the 3.x, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4 and 4.5 API's and haven't been able to decipher what happened to some of the Packages,  Classes, and Interfaces.

`-MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager
-HttpConnectionManagerParams
-HostConfiguration
-HttpMethod
-HttpStatus
-URI
-StringRequestEntity`

If anyone can help me figure this out I'd be most appreciative.